# Wordpress move to multisite redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, multisite

I am in the process of moving a live wordpress site to a multisite. I have a staging environment setup, that is a subdomain of the live site: staging.domain.com. This subdomain points to a different server to the live environment, but has been setup in an identical manner. The database it uses is a copy of the live environments database. I want to first get the multisite fully operational on the staging environment before I replicate the changes to live.

I have successfully allowed multisite buy setting the following in the wp-config: `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );`

However, in following the next step, an unusual thing happens. After deactivating the plugins I change the wp-config again with the following changes:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'staging.domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

and applying the suggested changes to the .htaccess file, I restart apache and re-visit staging.domain.com in the browser. Here's the problem:

I am immediately redirected to `domain.com` (the live environment), and can no longer visit the staging site in the browser. If I go back to the staging server and remove those changes to the wp-config (remove those definitions from the wp-config) then everything returns back to normal, but they're necessary for multisite.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs saved in the database need to be updated when you change environments.

**Steps to update URLs in a WordPress database:**

1. Export the database to a .sql file (include a drop table statement)
2. Save a copy of the export as a backup
3. Open the .sql file in a code editor
4. Find and replace all occurrences of `domain.com` with `staging.domain.com`
5. Overwrite the database with the updated .sql file